# Opening files on a Linux machine from Windows

Tags: linux

I'm a Linux noob. I recently need to work with stuff on a few Linux machines but I'm on Windows and want to just open files in my Windows apps (like Visual Studio or Notepad++).

Is there an easy way without spending 5 minutes WinSCPing files around? Can I map a drive to some root dollar share or something on Linux?

Luke

Comment: Just a head's up Luke, be sure to take note of the ways each handles files.  Depending on the program you use, you could accidentally litter a file intended for Unix with Windows line endings and ANSI.  In notepad++, as I assume you know, you can change it to "Unix" and "UTF-8" or whatever your need is.  @terdon is right, that's probably the easiest solution (below) if you have access to set-up a samba share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to export a drive from the Linux box to your windows machine, the easiest thing to do  would be to set up an SMB share. There is a good guide for Ubuntu [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide). I would be happy to give you more details if you specify which Linux distribution you are using. The basic setup is the same for all but details may change.

Answer (score 2):

You can also mount Linux file systems through SSH. This is called SSHFS. This solution will be preferable if you are not willing to set up anything on the Linux servers. In Windows there are alternative clients to do this, like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/). With new Windows and Linux versions Windows clients sometimes break up, but you can try it anyway.

Another alternative you might want to consider is setting up public key authentication, so that WinSCP would be more integrated to your Windows environment. There is a guide for public key authentication [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter8.html). However this does not give you perfect integration, you can not see remote file system in "Open File" dialogs provided by Windows.

Comment: Thanks. For me, sadly, the SSH lib that SSHFS depends on has an installer that isn't Windows 8 compatible.

Comment: @LukePuplett You could also use a utility such as WinSCP.
http://winscp.net/eng/index.php
Not sure if Win8 compatible.